# Error installing wine on POP!_OS

Tags: apt, wine

When I run `sudo apt install wine-stable` on Pop!_OS 19.10 I get the following error

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 libblkid1 i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 libmount1 i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 libuuid1 i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libblkid1_2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libmount1_2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libuuid1_2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

This is my sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 19.10 _Eoan Ermine_ - Release amd64 (20200131)]/ eoan main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary eoan main
# deb-src http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary eoan main
```

This is the result of running `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libratbag-piper/piper-libratbag-git/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                     
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                         
Ign:5 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                             
Hit:6 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                               
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                          
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Hit:9 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary eoan InRelease   
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Fetched 284 kB in 1s (251 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
```

EDIT 2
And this is the result of `apt policy wine-stable libblkid1`:

```
wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.0~eoan
  Version table:
     5.0.0~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.3~eoan 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe i386 Packages
libblkid1:
  Installed: 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1
  Candidate: 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.34-0.1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
```

Can anyone advise on how I might fix this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your package index is outdated as the error message suggests.

Try again with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine-stable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, this doesn't fix it. I've added the result of `sudo apt update` to the question..

Comment: Did you get the same error? After the update apt should now be aware that e.g. `libblkid1_2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb` was replaced by [libblkid1_2.34-0.1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libblkid1_2.34-0.1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb). Please try `sudo apt update --fix-missing` followed by `sudo apt install -f` to fix the errors first and post the output if that fails.

Comment: I ran both of these with no errors. But still installing wine throws the same error

Comment: I'm a bit clueless as to why the same error occurs. What is the output of `apt policy wine-stable libblkid1`? Another option could be to clean the apt cache manually...

Comment: I've just pasted the result of `apt policy wine-stable libblkid1` in the original question. Is this where the error is coming from?

Comment: Looks like it. And it's strange that [libblkid1 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan-updates/libblkid1) is not found. Not good. I would try the installation guide from [wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).